# Jquery how to check every value on select with same ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple select option. I want to check if any select has specific selected value then disable a button. is possible to do that ?

here the example :

```
<select class='test'>
<option value='open'>AA</option>
<option value='hide'>BB</option>
</select>

<select class='test'>
<option value='open'>AA</option>
<option value='hide'>BB</option>
</select>

<button id='bb'></button>
```

so if there is any select with `class 'test'` is selected with `'hide'` value, then button with `id 'bb'` is disabled. 
Even if I select another `select option` with open value, if there is still one `select` with hide value left, the button should still disabled.
I want to do that with jQuery.

Comment: It sure is possible. Give it a try - and if you can't get it to work, that's when we can help you.

Comment: You can use `eq()` to get the `select.test` by index. I'll recommend to use unique ID on each `select` element to identify them.

Comment: ok how do I do that ?? I have no Idea how ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I understand, if any of the dropdown is selected as `hide` then the button should get disabled. So, if you select `BB` option, then button gets disabled and if you select `AA` option, then button gets enabled.

Here is the updated code:

```js
function checkAndDisableButton() {
  $("#bb").prop('disabled', false);
  $(".test").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'hide') {
      $("#bb").prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
}


$("select").on('change', checkAndDisableButton);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='test'>
<option value='open'>AA</option>
<option value='hide'>BB</option>
</select>

<select class='test'>
<option value='open'>AA</option>
<option value='hide'>BB</option>
</select>

<button id='bb'>Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, it will check if any `select` has an selected option with the value of hide. If so, it will disable the button.

```
$(".test").change(function() {
  var flag = true;
  $('.test').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "hide") {
      flag = false;
    }
  });
  if (flag) {
    $("#bb").prop("disabled", false)
  } else {
    $("#bb").prop("disabled", true)
  }
})
```

**Working demo**

```js
$(".test").change(function() {
  var flag = true;
  $('.test').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "hide") {
      flag = false;
    }
  });
  if (flag) {
    $("#bb").prop("disabled", false)
  } else {
    $("#bb").prop("disabled", true)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='test'>
<option value='open'>AA</option>
<option value='hide'>BB</option>
</select>

<select class='test'>
<option value='open'>AA</option>
<option value='hide'>BB</option>
</select>

<button id='bb'>test me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple if,bonus: no loop :)

```
    $(".test").change(function() {

      if($('.test option:selected').is('[value="hide"]')) {
        $("#bb").prop("disabled", true)
      } else {
        $("#bb").prop("disabled", false)
      }
    })
```

demo:

```js
$(".test").change(function() {

  if ($('.test option:selected').is('[value="hide"]')) {
    $("#bb").prop("disabled", true)
  } else {
    $("#bb").prop("disabled", false)
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='test'>
<option value='open'>AA</option>
<option value='hide'>BB</option>
</select>

<select class='test'>
<option value='open'>AA</option>
<option value='hide'>BB</option>
</select>

<button id='bb'>test me</button>
```